# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Authorization Header

Tags: powershell, authorization, basic-authentication, powershell-4.0, invoke-restmethod

While invoking an `Invoke-RestMethod` using Powershell like:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://google.com/api/GetData" -Headers $headers
```

and `$headers` being

```
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Secret $username $password"
    Content='application/json'
}
```

What is the format expected for the parameters `$username` and `$password`?

Answer (score 26):

As far as I know you have to send a OAuth2 token in the request headers.

```
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer $token"
}
```

Perhaps the following blog post gives you an idea how to do so.
https://lazyadmin.nl/it/connect-to-google-api-with-powershell/

Comment: The cleaner way now would be to do `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Authentication Bearer -Token ($TokenString | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText)`

Answer (score 8):

Solution provide by **Rufer7** is right. I just want to add one more thing you can also pass the content parameter in Invoke-WebRequest method keeping the header more simple like this and getting the output in Json format. So my refined script will look like this.

**Powershell Script:**

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12


$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer $token"
}

$responseData = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json").Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

First line is optional only if you observe this error otherwise you can ignore this.

**"Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."**

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, I used `username` and `password` in the body of the REST API call.
My body is:

```
$body = [PSCustomObject] @{
  username=$Credential.UserName; 
  password=$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password;
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

In the function I use the PSCredential class:

```
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
$Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty,
```

Eventually, I call it this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://google.com/api/GetData" -ContentType application/json -Body $body
```

The `ContentType` is set, because I expect JSON in response.