# Trying to get spotify API sample using curl in PowerShell

Tags: javascript, powershell, curl, spotify

I keep getting this error in my power point after running the above code (to get an artist from Spotify API) :

```
curl --request GET \ --url https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4aawyAB9vmqN3uQ7FjRGTy \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX'

At line:2 char:5
+   --url 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Lilbaby&type=artist' \
+     ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:2 char:5
+   --url 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Lilbaby&type=artist' \
+     ~~~
Unexpected token 'url' in expression or statement.
At line:3 char:5
+   --header 'Authorization: Bearer BQCr8A...QoBCa4'
+     ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:3 char:5
+   --header 'Authorization: Bearer BQCr8A...QoBCa4'
+     ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

I have tried it multiple times but still the same result

Comment: In *some* versions of Powershell,```curl``` is an alias for ```Invoke-WebRequest``` (see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5870) - try ```curl.exe``` instead to bypass the alias and invoke the executable, or just convert the call to using ```Invoke-WebRequest``` instead…

Comment: The options with two dashes are not needed.  See : https://curl.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell

##### For albums

```
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer ####### your access token ######"
    Content='application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4aawyAB9vmqN3uQ7FjRGTy" -Headers $headers
```

Result
[image]

##### For artists

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Lilbaby&type=artist" -Headers $headers
$releases | get-member 
$releases.artists
```

Result
[image]

##### References

#1 [curl in PowerShell](https://www.educative.io/answers/curl-in-powershell)

#2 [Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191266/powershell-invoke-restmethod-authorization-header)

#3 [Wrangling REST APIs with PowerShell JSON Examples](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-json/)